# How do I rescan drives I've expanded?

Tags: vmware, lvm, scsi

I frequently expand drives on my VMs. How can I rescan the drives without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use scsitools script rescan-scsi-bus.

```
sudo apt-get install scsitools
sudo rescan-scsi-bus
```

To do it without installing a utility on 14.04:

```
echo '1' > /sys/class/scsi_disk/0\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan
```

**IMPORTANT:** Be sure to replace the 0:0:0:0 with the appropriate disk for your purposes.

Answer (score 8):

Example for system disk without reboot:

- Rescan the bus for the new size:

  ```
  # echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
  ```
- Expand your partition (works with ansible):

  ```
  # parted ---pretend-input-tty /dev/sda resizepart F 2 Yes 100%
  - F for Fix 
  - 2 for partition
  - Yes to confirm
  - 100% for whole partition
  ```
- Resize it:

  ```
  # resize2fs /dev/sda2
  ```